# PHP request to FRAPI action not executing, returning null

Tags: php, ssl, frapi

I'm not sure what changed in the system I'm working on, but all of a sudden FRAPI stopped giving responses to requests I make.

For example, I have an action with an executePost() function that returns a string of hex values. I have code that converts this returned value into a binary string with

```
$binstr = hextobin($response->result);
```

but lately it has been giving me

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in DIRECTORY
```

This is not just this function or this FRAPI action, but all FRAPI actions across the rather large system.

Initially I was stumped, then I noticed that I was receiving system mail in /var/spool/mail/root with the following message:

> ################# SSL Certificate Warning ################
>   Certificate for hostname '*.MYHOSTNAME.com', in file (or by nickname):
>         /etc/httpd/ssl/certs/MYHOSTNAME.com.crt
>
> The certificate needs to be renewed; this can be done using the
>   'genkey' program.
>
> Browsers will not be able to correctly connect to this web site
>   using SSL until the certificate is renewed.

Hoping that this was the problem I self-signed the cert using genkey and... nothing. Was it just a coincidence that this happened around the same time?

The issue still occurs and I'm stumped.

I also tested the FRAPI actions using the Tester in the Admin control panel and the responses were valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - it was an issue with https. Perhaps the self-signed key wasn't generated correctly or FRAPI was not recognizing the new key, but the reason why the tester was working and outside connections weren't is that FRAPI does not use SSL for testing. I just changed my connections to FRAPI from https:// to http:// and everything started working again.